# How to import Javascript package in browser via script tag or similar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I know I'm a bit behind the times here, but how can I import from [this library](https://github.com/ui-router/react-hybrid) (uirouter/react-hybrid) for an existing Angularjs site using only  tags to include libraries? I have tried a few things, including including from CDN via jsdelivr, also building from node locally and attempting to include the dependencies via webpack. I have also tried loading through require.js but not sure I did it correctly. No matter what, I either get an error for the import or I fail to see the library once imported. I am just not getting it, I feel like I'm missing something. Could someone please help me with a detailed process for how I can get this library to work in place of the existing angular ui-router loaded via  tag?

I could definitely go into the reasons why I'm doing this in the first place if necessary, but I feel like this should be pretty simple and I'm just struggling.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Dominik, thanks for the reply... If you click on the link I provided for the library, the first few lines state: `UI-Router support for Hybrid Angular/React apps
This package enables UI-Router to route to both AngularJS components (and/or templates) and React components. Your app will be hosted by AngularJS while you incrementally migrate to React.`

Comment: Fair... I admit I did not click the link. :) Carry on. Probably best to remove the react tags then